# How to use an older version of sveltekit?

Tags: npm-install, sveltekit

How can I start an older SvelteKit version with npm?
I have tried

```
npm init svelte@next.104 
npm init sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.104
npm init @sveltejs/kit/@1.0.0-next.104
```

and similar combinations without success. I get (for example):

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@sveltejs%2fcreate-kit - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@sveltejs/create-kit@1.0.0-next.104' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-09T13_53_44_704Z-debug.log
Install for [ '@sveltejs/create-kit@1.0.0-next.104' ] failed with code 1
```

I want to use an older version (104), because
https://codesandbox.io/s/3dxrg  uses Swiper 7.0.3 and SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.104

See also my question at [Sveltekit: Cannot find module 'swiper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113480/sveltekit-cannot-find-module-swiper)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm init svelte@next` runs the `bin` of the package [`create-svelte`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/create-svelte/) ([NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-init)) which is versioned and released separately from the main kit package. In addition, the templates produced are not pinned to a specific kit version.

If you need to use an older version of SvelteKit, you would need to manually downgrade the version after bootstrapping a project. You can use the latest `create-svelte` version at the time of the release of kit `v1.0.0-next.104`, which I believe is `create-svelte@2.0.0-next.71` after looking at the changelog git histories ([`create-svelte`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/create-svelte/CHANGELOG.md)/[`kit`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/kit/CHANGELOG.md)).

Run:

```
npm init svelte@2.0.0-next.71
```

then change `package.json` to use

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/kit": "1.0.0-next.104",
...
```

then `npm install` as normal.

Keep in mind that since SvelteKit is beta and changes happen quickly, you may run into other dependency issues when using an older version.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.